# Convert an array of tuples in Athena SQL to a formatted table

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

Is there a way to convert the following data (an array of "tuples") in Athena SQL to the following format?

**Note**: that the number of items in the array is not defined and there can be many, but they are always paired.

From:

```json
[1234, 1, 5678, 2, ..., 9012, 3]
```

To:

| ID | Val |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 |
| 5678 | 2 |
| 9012 | 3 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With provided data you can try next approach - [`unnest`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) the array with ordinality, group using the ordinality into array and then extract members of the array:

```sql
select try(agg [ 1 ]) id,
    try(agg [ 2 ]) val
from (
        select (a - 1) / 2 grp, -- group determined from ordinality
            array_agg(n) agg -- aggregated array with up to 2 members
        from (select array[1234, 1, 5678, 2, 9012, 3] arr) -- initial data
        cross join unnest(arr) WITH ORDINALITY AS t (n, a)
        group by 1
    )
order by grp
```

Output:

| id | val |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1 |
| 5678 | 2 |
| 9012 | 3 |